# QJsonValue::isUndefined does not work correctly

Tags: json, qt, qt5

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char json[] = "{ id: 12}";
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
    QJsonValue v = doc.object()["no-defined"];
    Q_ASSERT(v.isUndefined());  // assert failed.

    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to use `QJsonValue::isUndefined()` to judge if I define the key, but in the test code, `v.isUndefined()` return false, not true. I don't know the reason, is there any  explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running a test:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char json[] = "{ id: 12}";
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
    QJsonValue v_ar = doc.object()["no-defined"];
    QJsonValue v_o = doc.object().value(QString("no-defined"));
    qDebug() << "Array-operator:" << v_ar.isUndefined() << v_ar.toString() << v_ar.type(); //returns: false ""
    qDebug() << "Object-operator:" << v_o.isUndefined() << v_o.toString(); //returns true ""
    qDebug() << "direct object call:" << doc.object().value("no-defined").isUndefined() << doc.object().value("no-defined").toString(); //returns true ""
    qDebug() << "direct array call:" << doc.object()["no-defined"].isUndefined() << doc.object()["no-defined"].toString(); //returns false ""
    return a.exec();
}
```

which results in:

```
Array-operator: false "" 0
Object-operator: true ""
direct object call: true ""
direct array call: false ""
```

You can see that there is something wrong with the array operator. Instead of returning a JsonValue::Undefined it returns a JsonValue::NULL (0). A way around would be using

```
QJsonValue v = doc.object().value("no-defined");
```

or better:

```
Q_ASSERT(doc.object().value("no-defined").isUndefined());
```

According to [QT-BUG](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39864) it is meant that way. If you call the array operator a new item is created with a default value of NULL.